# Proving that $\int_0^3\frac{\arctan\sqrt{x^2+6}}{\sqrt{x^2+6}}\mathrm{d}x>\frac4\pi$

Tags: integration, inequality

I would like to prove the following inequality:

$$\int_0^3\frac{\arctan\left(\sqrt{x^2+6}\right)}{\sqrt{x^2+6}}\mathrm{d}x>\frac4\pi\quad\color{blue}{(*)}$$

I have tried to prove it by changing variable, by using the formula of integration by parts and also methods of numerical integration such as Simpson’s Rule but I did not manage to.

Please, could you help me ?

Does anyone know the proof of the following inequalities which could be useful in order to prove $\,(*)\,$ ?

If $f''(x)$ is a convex function on the interval $\,[a,b]\,,\,$ then

$$\big(b-a\big)f\!\left(\frac{a+b}2\right)+\frac13\left(\frac{b-a}2\right)^{\!3}f''\!\left(\frac{a+b}2\right)\leqslant\int_a^b\!\!f(x)\mathrm{d}x \\ \leqslant\frac{b-a}6\left[f(a)+4f\!\left(\frac{a+b}2\right)+f(b)\right]\;.$$

**Another possible attempt :**

Since $$\int_0^3\frac{\arctan\left(\sqrt{x^2+6}\right)}{\sqrt{x^2+6}}\mathrm{d} x=\int_0^{\frac\pi3}\!\!\int_0^{\frac\pi3}\frac{\mathrm{d} x\mathrm{d} y}{\sin^2\!x+\cos^2\!y}$$

Could anyone help me to prove $\,(*)\,$ by using the double integral ?

Comment: This looks like it will call for a rather careful argument or fairly high-precision calculation via series expansion:  the definite integral _per_ WA is only about $ \ 8 · 10^{-5} \ $ larger than $ \ \frac{4}{\pi} \ . $

Comment: @boojum, yes, you are right, indeed the definite integral is only $0.00008$ larger than $\frac4\pi\;.$ For that reason I could not prove the inequality.

Comment: Tall things in titles are [discouraged](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9687).

Comment: As @metamorphy told you, "tall things", I.e.  displaystyle, are not welcome in titles.

Answer (score 3):

**Some thoughts**:

With the substitution $\sqrt{x^2 + 6} = y$, we have
$$I = \int_{\sqrt{6}}^{\sqrt{15}} \frac{\arctan y}{\sqrt{y^2 - 6}} \mathrm{d} y.$$

Let
\begin{align*}
 g(y) &= \arctan\sqrt6 + \frac{1}{7}(y - \sqrt 6) - \frac{\sqrt6}{49}(y - \sqrt6)^2 + \frac{17}{1029}(y - \sqrt6)^3 \\
 &\quad - \frac{5\sqrt6}{2401}(y - \sqrt6)^4 + 
 \frac{121}{84035}(y - \sqrt6)^5 - \frac{17\sqrt6}{117649}(y - \sqrt6)^6. 
\end{align*}
*Note*: $g(y)$ is the 6th order Taylor approximation of $\arctan y$ around $y = \sqrt6$.

*Fact 1*: $\arctan y \ge g(y)$ for all $y\in [\sqrt6, \sqrt{15}]$.
(*Proof*: Let $F(y) = \arctan y - g(y)$. We have
$F'(y) = \frac{\sqrt6\, (612y - 235\sqrt6)(y - \sqrt6)^6}{705894(1 + y^2)} \ge 0$ for all $y\in [\sqrt6, \sqrt{15}]$. Also, $F(\sqrt6) = 0$. Thus,
$F(y) \ge 0$ for all $y\in [\sqrt6, \sqrt{15}]$.)

By Fact 1, we have
\begin{align*}
 I &\ge \int_{\sqrt{6}}^{\sqrt{15}} \frac{g(y)}{\sqrt{y^2 - 6}} \mathrm{d} y\\
 &= \arctan\sqrt6 \cdot \ln\frac{\sqrt{15} + 3}{\sqrt6} - \frac{295997}{168070}\sqrt6\, \ln\frac{\sqrt{15} + 3}{\sqrt6}\\
 &\quad + \frac{38203311}{2941225} - \frac{631395}{235298} \sqrt{10}\\
 &> \frac{4}{\pi}.\tag{1}
\end{align*}

---

Explanations for (1):

i) By using the 7th order Taylor approximation of $\arctan u$ around $u = \sqrt{3}$, we can prove that (similar to the proof of Fact 1)
$$\arctan\sqrt6 \ge \frac{3253}{8960}\sqrt6 - \frac{3897}{8960}\sqrt3 + \frac{\pi}{3} \triangleq A.$$

ii) We have
$$\ln\frac{\sqrt{15} + 3}{\sqrt6} = 1 + \ln \left(1 + \frac{\frac{\sqrt{15} + 3}{\sqrt6} - \mathrm{e}}{\mathrm{e}}\right).$$

By using $\ln(1 + v) \ge v - \frac{1}{2}v^2$ for all $v \ge 0$, we have
$$\ln\frac{\sqrt{15} + 3}{\sqrt6}
\ge \frac{\sqrt{6} + \sqrt{10}}{\mathrm{e}}- \frac{\sqrt{15} + 4}{2\mathrm{e}^2} - \frac12 \triangleq B.$$

By using $\ln(1 + v) \le v - \frac12 v^2 + \frac13v^3$ for all $v \ge 0$, we have
\begin{align*}
\ln\frac{\sqrt{15} + 3}{\sqrt6}
&\le \frac{3\sqrt6 + 3\sqrt{10}}{2\mathrm{e}} - \frac{3\sqrt{15} + 12}{2\mathrm{e}^2} + \frac{9\sqrt{6} + 7\sqrt{10}}{6\mathrm{e}^3} - \frac{5}{6}\\
&\triangleq C.
\end{align*}

Now, by i) and ii), it suffices to prove that
$$
 A B - \frac{295997}{168070}\sqrt6\, C
 + \frac{38203311}{2941225} - \frac{631395}{235298} \sqrt{10}
 > \frac{4}{\pi}.
$$
This inequality involves $\pi, \mathrm{e}, \sqrt{3}, \sqrt{6}, \sqrt{10}, \sqrt{15}$ which can be estimated in terms of factions, e.g. $\frac{191210837}{60466176} < \sqrt{10} < \frac{15934237}{5038848}$. I omit this part.

Comment: How do you show the integral is greater than $4/\pi$(The last one)

Comment: @RiverLi, please could you prove the following inequalities ? If $f''(x)$ is a convex function on the interval $\,[a,b]\,,\,$ then

$$\big(b-a\big)f\!\left(\frac{a+b}2\right)+\frac13\left(\frac{b-a}2\right)^{\!3}f''\!\left(\frac{a+b}2\right)\leqslant\int_a^b\!\!f(x)\mathrm{d}x \\ \leqslant\frac{b-a}6\left[f(a)+4f\!\left(\frac{a+b}2\right)+f(b)\right]\;.$$

Comment: @AdityaDwivedi We may estimate $\arctan \sqrt{6}$ and $\ln\frac{\sqrt{15} + 3}{\sqrt6}$ etc. by using Taylor approximation. I will add some details soon.

Comment: @Angelo Did you search the literature of integral inequalities?

Comment: @RiverLi, yes, I did but I have not found any proof. Please, could you tell me the proof of that integral inequalities ?

Comment: @Angelo Does the integral inequality solve your problem? Also, do you mean the 2nd derivative $f''(x)$ is a convex function?

Comment: @RiverLi, it would solve my problem with less calculations because $f’’(x)$ is convex on $[0,1]$ and is concave on $[1,3]$. If you proved that integral inequalities in the case that $f’’(x)$ is convex, it would be trivial to prove that the reverse integral inequalities are correct in the case that $f’’(x)$ is concave. So I would solve my problem.

Comment: @Angelo $f(x) = \frac{\arctan\left(\sqrt{x^2+6}\right)}{\sqrt{x^2+6}}$? Then $f''(x)$ is convex on [0, c), concave on (c, 3] where $c \approx 1.005986132$. Another question is: is it easy to prove that $f''(x)$ is convex/concave on those intervals?

Comment: @RiverLi, I thought it was concave on $[1,3]$. Perhaps it would be better to solve my problem by using the double integral $$\int_0^{\frac\pi3}\!\!\int_0^{\frac\pi3}\frac{\mathrm{d} x\mathrm{d} y}{\sin^2\!x+\cos^2\!y} $$Please, could you try to ?

Comment: @Angelo Did you check $f^{(4)}(1)$? It seems $f^{(4)}(1) > 0$. I have no idea for the double integral. I check the literature for integral inequality involving $\int_a^b f(x) \mathrm{d}x$ which is usually related to the bounds for $f'$ or $f''$ on $[a, b]$. Your claim does not depend on these information.

Comment: @RiverLi, yes, you are right, actually $f^{(4)}(x)>0$ for all $[0,c)$. I was wrong when I thought that $f’’(x)$ was concave on $[1,3]$. I did hope that it was simplier to prove that $$\int_0^{\frac\pi3}\!\!\int_0^{\frac\pi3}\frac{\mathrm{d} x\mathrm{d} y}{\sin^2\!x+\cos^2\!y}>\frac4\pi$$ Please, try to prove it.

Comment: @Angelo It is easily to obtain another double integral $I = \int_0^3 \int_0^1 \frac{1}{1 + t^2(x^2 + 6)}\mathrm{d} t \mathrm{d} x$.

Comment: @Angelo Use $\frac{\arctan u}{u} = \int_0^1 \frac{1}{1 + t^2 u^2}\mathrm{d} t$.

Comment: @RiverLi, please could you prove that $$\displaystyle\int_0^3\!\!\!\int_0^1\!\!\frac1{1+t^2\left(x^2+6\right)}\mathrm{d}t \mathrm{d}x>\frac4\pi\;\;?$$

Comment: No, if you want much less calculations. Your integral inequality is nice, where does it come from?  I searched the literature and found Atkinson's inequality: \begin{align*}
 \int_a^b f(x) \mathrm{d} x &\ge \frac{1}{2}(b - a)[f(a) + f(b)] - \frac{1}{12}(b - a)^2[f'(b) - f'(a)]\\
 &\quad - \frac{1}{384}(b - a)^4\int_a^b \max(- f^{(4)}(x), 0)\mathrm{d} x.
\end{align*} If $f''$ is convex i.e. $f^{(4)}(x) \ge 0$, then it becomes $$\int_a^b f(x) \mathrm{d} x  \ge \frac{1}{2}(b - a)[f(a) + f(b)] - \frac{1}{12}(b - a)^2[f'(b) - f'(a)].$$

Comment: Also, \begin{align*}
 \int_a^b f(x) \mathrm{d} x &\ge (b - a)f\left(\frac{a + b}{2}\right) + \frac{1}{24}(b - a)^2[f'(b) - f'(a)]\\
 &\quad - \frac{1}{384}(b - a)^4\int_a^b \max( f^{(4)}(x), 0)\mathrm{d} x.
\end{align*} If $f''$ is concave i.e. $f^{(4)}(x) \le 0$, then it becomes $$\int_a^b f(x) \mathrm{d} x \ge (b - a)f\left(\frac{a + b}{2}\right) + \frac{1}{24}(b - a)^2[f'(b) - f'(a)].$$

Answer (score 2):

Well, since you mentioned Simpson's rules and numerical methods, if you are okay with numerical methods and brute force, you can note that since $x>\arctan (x)$ in the region of integration (Easily proven by taking the derivative of $x-\arctan x$),  your function is monotonically decreasing.  Thus a right handed Riemann sum will always be a lower bound for your integral.  Grab your favorite CAS or Excel or whatnot and keep plugging in different values of $n$ for your partition size until your lower bound gets high enough (Note to be formally true, you'll have to also account for the tiny error in the numerical estimates involved in the program's calculation of $\arctan$ and $\sqrt x$,  but both of those are also boundable.

I'm sure there's a more elegant approach, but hey, sometimes all you have is a hammer....

Comment: Alan, why are you using Riemann sums ? Simpson’s Rule only requires $n=6$ and it is better than Riemann sums. The reason for which I would prefer not to use numerical methods is that they require an accurate calculator, whereas I am looking for a solution without using calculators.

Comment: Mostly because the last time I looked at numerical approximation methods was about 8 years ago, so this was the first thing that came to mind.

Comment: @Alan One of my favorite numerical integration methods is to the draw the function in Microsoft Paint, fill in the area below and then check the file size :)

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch I'll keep that!